# How to create a To field like the one in Mail or Facebook app?

Tags: iphone, uikit

Does anyone know how to create a 'To field' like the one in Mail or Facebook app?

When an address is added from the A-Z list, a blue component that represents the address will be added to the text field. Is there a class provided for this functionality, or do we have to implement by ourselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in framework. You'll either need to implement it yourself or use one of the open source components, such as [Three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20) (which includes the one used in the Facebook app).

Answer (score 1):

In Three20's author's [blog](http://joehewitt.com/post/the-three20-project/) I found these few lines:

> Message composer
>
> TTMessageController emulates the
>   message composer in Apple's Mail app.
>   You can customize it to send any kind
>   of message you want. Include your own
>   set of message fields, **or use the
>   standard "To:" and "Subject:"**.
>   Recipient names can be autocompleted
>   from a data source that you provide.

Maybe you should take a look at its [source code](https://github.com/facebook/three20/) at github.