# Implementing a To-field as in mail.app

Tags: iphone, email

Is there a way to get the To-field, as it is implemented in mail.app, into my app easily? If not, how would you go about creating such an advanced component that has manual text entry, "packaging" of entered addresses in "blue boxes", line wrapping and a '+' button to access the address book?

(I already have the code necessary to pick out contacts/e-mail addresses, I'm only asking about the To-field.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the TTMessageController in Three20 is what you're looking for, according to this question: [How to create a To field like the one in Mail or Facebook app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713478/how-to-create-a-to-field-like-the-one-in-mail-or-facebook-app)